# Plotting a table choosing the x-axis numbers yourself

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have got a vector with y values:

```
{{{0.}}, {{0.0572114}}, {{0.108052}}, {{0.1592}}, {{0.211456}}, {{0.263981}}, 
 {{0.316622}}, {{0.369211}}, {{0.421765}}, {{0.474278}}, {{0.526757}}}
```

The corresponding x-values are

```
{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0}.
```

How can I plot the values in the vector with the corresponding x-values? (I might scale the number of values up to 1000 in the future, so was a hoping for a method that can be used in that case as well. Also I would prefer a way that gives me a line, not only the points.)

Comment: Look up Flatten,  ListPlot, DataRange

Answer (score 2):

One way to make the plot is

```
yData =
  {{{0.}}, {{0.0572114}}, {{0.108052}}, {{0.1592}}, {{0.211456}}, {{0.263981}}, 
   {{0.316622}}, {{0.369211}}, {{0.421765}}, {{0.474278}}, {{0.526757}}};
xData = Range[0, 1, .1];

ListPlot[Transpose[{xData, Flatten @ yData}]]
```

[image: plot]